# How to find a subset of numbers such that its average is close to the average of the full set?

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-programming

I have a set of *n* numbers whose average (arithmetic mean) is *x*. I have to choose a subset of *k* numbers from *n* such that its average is closest to *x*. Please note that *k* is the upper bound. If the average can be represented with less than *k* numbers, then that set is chosen.

For example:
set = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} (n = 6) (average = 3.5)
If k = 1 then the subset can be either {3} or {4}
If k = 2 then the subset is {3, 4}
If k = 3 then the subset is still {3, 4}

I have to write an algorithm for the same. If this problem is not solvable in polynomial time, what would be a good approach to solve it? Any heuristic approach?

Comment: Your problem should be hard. You can get a good solution by random sampling.

Comment: Do you know the target average value in advance or is it unknown ?

Comment: The target value is not known in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are allowed to use a solver for this, but this problem can be easily formulated as a Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming (MINLP) problem.

[image]

This can be solved with open source solvers like [Couenne](https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne) or [Bonmin](http://www.coin-or.org/Bonmin/). Actually this model can be linearized so it can even be solved with linear Mixed Integer Programming (MIP) solvers.

Comment: A linearized version of the model can be found [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2015/12/find-subset-with-same-mean.html). This version can be solved with any MIP solver.